# Ajax REST: PUT/DELETE não funciona

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, cross-domain, cors

Tenho 2 aplicações:

1) uma API Rest num servidor XPTO (Usando laravel 5.1), que possui:

```
  ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*.xpto.com.br')
  ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
  ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE')
  ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description');
```

2) No meu Client: Front estático que faz AJAX GET/POST/PUT/DELETE pra API acima.

O GET/POST acontece normal, mas quando faço um PUT/DELETE ele retorna:

> "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

O que não faz muito sentido, pois se não tivesse o Origin, nem o POST funcionaria.

Método que utilizo:

```
var objXPTO = function() {
    ...
    this.Ajax = function(url,type,args,callback) {
            //console.log(url,type,args,callback);
            $.ajax({
                 url: url,
                 method: type,
                 data: args
                }).done(function(data) {
                 callback(data);
            });
        }
    ...

}
```

Aquém tem alguma luz?

Comment: coloca `_method: 'PUT'` como argumento e testa a chamada.

Comment: @bgsouza, funcionou com a ajuda do comentário acima?

Comment: Olá @Ruggi e Marco
Testei assim e nao rolou

Meu codigo estava certo, vi hoje que o problema era o CSRF do Laravel 5.1

Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Então @bgsouza responda sua própria pergunta e a responda, assim alguém que tiver o mesmo problema que você saberá como lidar com a situação.

Comment: @Ruggi decsulpe mas a usabilidade disso aqui é horrivel

Answer (score 1):

Galera consegui resolver meu problema, na verdade foi o CSRF do Laravel que estava me bloqueando Eu resolvi implementando um token :)